# Manage Azure-Account within code

Tags: azure

Is it possible to mange an azure account within code? Like

```
var ac = new AzureAccount(name, password);
ac.CreateStorageAccount(name);
ac.CreateCoAdmin(name);
...
```

I already know about the Azure cmdlets, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look at the Service Management API. There is an operation that allows you to create a storage account for example (comes with a C# example): [Create Storage Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh264518.aspx).

Adding a co-admin on the other hand won't be that simple. I believe there's support in the Service Management API to manage co-admins. If this is really important to you you can try to look at how the portal does it. You'll see that it executes 2 requests to add a co-admin to a subscription:

1. Call https://manage.windowsazure.com/Users/GetPrincipalId with the email address of the new admin. This will return a "LiveID" (like 00053ACD9A5B316C).
2. Call https://manage.windowsazure.com/Users/AddCoAdministrator with the email address, the LiveId, and information about the subscription to add the user.

This isn't documented and before even calling these services you'll need to manage authentication first.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure accounts are created when user provide their personal information along with a financial source (i.e. Credit Card) which can pay the balance incurred by the services used by the specified user. Once you are logged into your account you can add more administration. This process is managed upto certain degree of control directly by the Windows Azure team and there is no API to automate these functionality for various reasons.

However once you have got a new Subscription to Windows Azure, you certainly can use REST API to exactly create new services (i.e Cloud Service, VM, Storage etc) which are available within your Subscription. To make it happen just create a new reference dll (or class) and add all the REST API to in and then use that reference (or class) to exactly call they way you want.